# How can i achieve following in Es6 using spreader and gather operator?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am checking if the selector has a certain class, id, or both.  If there is a match on id, class, or both, `eitherClassIdOrBoth()` pushes the selector into the `elements` array.  It works perfectly fine, but I was wondering if I could achieve this in ES6 using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

This is where it returns a boolean:

```
var idAndClassMatch = function(matchId, matchClass, matchBoth) {
return (
(matchBoth && matchId && matchClass) || (!matchBoth && (matchId || matchClass))); }
```

This is the function in which I want to use the spread operator:

```
var elements = []

function eitherClassIdOrBoth(
   selectId, selectClass, array, matchBoth, elements
) 
{

   for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var classSection = array[i].className.split(" ");
      var matchId = selectId !== undefined && array[i].id === selectId;
      var matchClass = classSection !== undefined && 
          classSection.indexOf(selectClass) !== -1;

      if (idAndClassMatch(matchId, matchClass, matchBoth)) {
          elements.push(array[i]); 
      }
   }
}
```

I am passing these values from an `if` statement:

```
if (arr.length === 2) {
    computedFunction.eitherClassIdOrBoth(
        selectId, selectClass, tags, false, Allelements
    );
}
```

Any help would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to write this logic, but the main point probably isn't ES6-specific.

The biggest thing that jumps out at me is that the main query of this whole function could be replaced with calls to [Element#matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) which checks an element based on a CSS selector. It isn't available consistently on older browsers, but it is trivial to load a polyfill to make sure it is available. Then your whole

```
computedFunction.eitherClassIdOrBoth(
    selectId, selectClass, tags, false, Allelements
);
```

call would just be

```
Allelements.push(
  ...tags.filter(tag => tag.matches(`.${selectClass}, [id="${selectId}"]`)
);
```

e.g. Use `.filter` and `.matches` to make a new array with just items with the given `tags` array, and then use an ES6 spread to easily push all the items into the `Allelements` array.

You seem to have a few cases where `selectClass` or `selectId` could be `undefined`, so you could also build that query up, e.g.

```
const selector = [
  selectClass ? `.${selectClass}` : "",
  selectId ? `[id="${selectId}"]` : "",
].filter(Boolean).join(",");
Allelements.push(
  ...tags.filter(tag => selector ? tag.matches(selector) : false
);
```

and for cases where `matchBoth` is `true`, you just join the selector with `""` instead of `","`. So you'd end up with

```
function eitherClassIdOrBoth(
   selectId, selectClass, array, matchBoth, elements
) {
    const selector = [
      selectClass ? `.${selectClass}` : "",
      selectId ? `[id="${selectId}"]` : "",
    ].filter(Boolean).join(matchBoth ? "" : ",");
    if (selector) {
      elements.push(...array.filter(tag => tag.matches(selector));
    }
}
```

if you wanted a general utility.